Аккордеон в плагине Jira через velocity template
Я делаю информационную панель в Jira, но из-за большого объема информации она может занимать много места на странице. Можно ли ее как-то свернуть с помощью html-элемента "аккордеон"? Я пытаюсь, но не получается.
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
 incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
  exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
 incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
 exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
 });
}
 </script> 

